# Installing Java Cryptography Extension in Debian

Tags: java, debian, jce

I need to install the JCE in my Wheezy machine.

According to the documentation, I should replace the files local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar in $java_home/lib/security. However, my system doesn't have these files, and just copying JCE's files there don't work, as my code is failing and looking for the error it seems to be due to the lack of JCE.

```
 [java] GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)
 [java]     at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:788)
 [java]     at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:342)
 [java]     at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:285)
 [java]     at mistic.id.krbAction.run(krbAction.java:44)
 [java]     at mistic.id.krbAction.run(krbAction.java:1)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
 [java]     at mistic.id.Server.acceptSecurityContext(Server.java:119)
 [java]     at mistic.id.Server.main(Server.java:70)
 [java] Caused by: KrbException: Checksum failed
 [java]     at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.decrypt(Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.java:102)
 [java]     at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.decrypt(Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.java:94)
 [java]     at sun.security.krb5.EncryptedData.decrypt(EncryptedData.java:177)
 [java]     at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(KrbApReq.java:278)
 [java]     at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(KrbApReq.java:144)
 [java]     at sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(InitSecContextToken.java:108)
 [java]     at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Krb5Context.java:771)
 [java]     ... 8 more
 [java] Caused by: java.security.GeneralSecurityException: Checksum failed
 [java]     at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.AesDkCrypto.decryptCTS(AesDkCrypto.java:451)
 [java]     at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.AesDkCrypto.decrypt(AesDkCrypto.java:272)
 [java]     at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256.decrypt(Aes256.java:76)
 [java]     at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.decrypt(Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.java:100)
 [java]     ... 14 more
```

So, how could I successfully install JCE in Debian?

Comment: First of all, the JCE is _already_ installed as part of any modern java installation.  What you are attempting to do is install the "full strength" cryptography policy.  The error message doesn't seem to me to indicate missing cryptography, but instead seems to indicate problems in the cryptographic exchange.

Comment: @jtahlborn you were right, the previous error was about a bad password. But now check this one